# Is it possible for windows authentication to not prompt the user for credentials?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I'm using iis 7, currently deployed on a test machine running windows 7 professional.

The computer is logged into the domain of my company.  In the past (at another company) I was able to use integrated authentication in ii6 and it wouldn't prompt the user if they were using IE.  It would just absorb their domain credentials.

However, that was initially setup by somebody else before I started.  I'm doing this project from scrap, and I'm a software engineer without much IIS experience.

This is the relevant snippit from my web.config file

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="false" />
```

I'm also running the app pool in v4.0 integrated.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On IIS disable anonymous authentication and activate Windows auth:
 - select your web application (or root if you app is place as root app)
 - select Authentication
 - disable Anonymous Authentication
 - enable Windows Authentication

Remember: for "automatic" login both your server and client must be in the same AD domanin or trusted domains.

Comment: Thanks, I looked around and tried adding the URL to the "Intranet sites" in IE settings and that did the trick.  Although it forced it into compatibility mode, which is another ball of wax.

Comment: Smeegs, strange.... "compatibility mode" is not necessary for "intranet sites". Try to remove it. Also consider to use Chrome: it's able to do integrated and automatic login. I use it that way and it's very good.

Comment: @Smeegs I was struggling with this issue and adding the site to `Intranet Sites` removed the login prompt

Comment: Young readers may need explaining that "Intranet Sites" was part of an MS Internet Explorer feature categorizing sites into zones for security purposes. Modern browsers have no equivalent !